# Древние слова

Tags: этимология, недопустимая-метка

Какие слова в русском языке являются самыми древними и имеют индоевропейские корни?

Answer (score 2):

Например, слово "пять". Оно имеет схожее звучание почти во всех языках Евразии.
Может, кто-то знает еще.

Answer (score 2):

К индоевропейскому праязыку-основе восходят слова, обозначающие растения, животных, металлы и минералы, орудия труда, формы хозяйствования, виды родства и т. д., например, дуб, лосось, гусь, волк, овца, медь, бронза, мед, мать, сын, дочь, ночь, луна, снег, вода, новый, шить.